# skimage.color.rgb2gray import trouble

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am having problem with importing `skimage.color` module. Although I can import and call `skimage.color.rgb2gray` from python shell, I cannot do the same thing from my application.

I checked `skimage` lib places on my PC. They all seems to be fine. But when I try to call skimage.color. from my code it always gives me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main-video2.py", line 44, in <module>
image = color.rgb2gray(image)
```

I checked the module like this

```
username@ubuntu:~/dev/computer_vision$ python 
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> 
 KeyboardInterrupt
 >>> from skimage import color 
 >>> color 
 <module 'skimage.color' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/color/__init__.pyc'>
```

Anybody can help me to understand why would be the reason while I'm able to call it from shell but not from my code ?

Comment: I think it probably isn't the module's fault – can you put your code in the question? (Also, if you're wondering if the error is due to the module not imported correctly, an `ImportError` should show up after your `image = color.rgb2gray(image)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you do not have the other libraries installed on your PC. Check [THIS PAGE](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html) and verify whether you have the required libraries required for runtime applications.

The reason for this error is because although `skimage` package  may be present and available (in python shell) you will not be able to run any application without the support of the other mentioned packages like : `matplotlib`, `scipy`, `pil`, `numpy` and `six`.

Visit the link to install/update the required packages.

Leave a comment if you still have a problem. :)

Comment: Thank you @Jeru Luke for the help. I solved the problem for a while ago just like you said. But forgot to update here. Reinstalling `skimage`  solved my problem.

Comment: @enterbutton Also as sansingh has answered, it is also good if you simultaneously start coding in OpenCV as well

Answer (score 3):

I have an alternative for you. You can use following code to convert a rgb image to gray:

```
# libraries
import cv2
import Image

# reading an image
image = cv2.imread(path_to_image)

# converting into gray image
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# saving image
Image.fromarray(gray_image).save(save_path)
```

Comment: Thank you @sansingh but since I am working with the skimage with other parts of my project. I don't prefer to work with the opencv

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using anaconda, restarting the kernel helps solve the issue. The bug is due to circular imports within `skimage.color` package itself.
In regular code, try `from skimage.io import imshow`. Saved me great amount of time [More on the subject](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3273)